# Rails 4: migrations with pk changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, migration

Ok, so, when you try to do a simple migration with data type changing its no big deal.

But there are some situations, when you need to change the type of primary key **with running production db**.

This bold statement is important, because rails doesn't give you a way to modify ids, justifying it with *"woooah, it can ruin your data integrity, so scary"*. But hey, i need to change the type and repopulate all the keys back **for the sake of this integrity**.

Okay, now you know the intro, let's dig in some code.

The following migration provides you with working database, but you could as well trash migrated tables, because the old ones become useless junk. Keep in mind, subject key is uuid right now, and we need to make it integer.

```
class RebuildOrdersIds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_column :orders, :id
    [:order_transitions, :order_items, :addresses].each do |table|
      remove_column table, :order_id
      add_column table, :order_id, :integer
    end
    Order.connection.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE order_index_seq START 100000;")
    Order.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE orders ADD COLUMN id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('order_index_seq');")
  end
  def down
    remove_column :orders, :id
    Order.connection.execute("DROP SEQUENCE order_index_seq;")
    add_column :orders, :id, :uuid, default: 'uuid_generate_v4()'
    Order.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT primakey PRIMARY KEY (id);")
    [:order_transitions, :order_items, :addresses].each do |table|
      remove_column table, :order_id
      add_column table, :order_id, :uuid
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, it removes old PKs and creates new columns of different data types.

If you need to save integrity of database, you might want to do something like this.

```
class RebuildOrdersIds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    #creating second temporary column for things. It might as well be new integer column.
    [:orders, :order_transitions,
      :order_items, :addresses].each do |table|
        add_column table, :old_order_id, :uuid
    end

    #mapping stuff together, setting either new values (start) or copying old ones
    mapping = {}
    start = 100000
    Order.all.each do |o|
      mapping[o] = {transitions: o.order_transitions,
                    items: o.order_items,
                    address: o.address}
    end
    mapping.each do |o|
      o[0].update_attribute(:old_order_id, o[0].id)
      o[1][:transitions].empty? || o[1][:transitions].each do |t|
        t.update_attribute(:old_order_id, o[0].id)
      end
      o[1][:items].empty? || o[1][:items].each do |i|
        i.update_attribute(:old_order_id, o[0].id)
      end
      o[1][:address].nil? || o[1][:address].update_attribute(:old_order_id, o[0].id)
      start += 1
    end

    #remove old columns, add some new
    remove_column :orders, :id
    [:order_transitions, :order_items, :addresses].each do |table|
      remove_column table, :order_id
      add_column table, :order_id, :integer
    end

    #making new column with counter with offset start
    Order.connection.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE order_index_seq START #{start};")
    Order.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE orders ADD COLUMN id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('order_index_seq');")
  end
end
```

So, there should be some code which populates "id" value as it should be.

The trouble is, nothing is working.
neither #update_attribute
nor #update_all
nor .id, .save

How can I achieve needed result?